# ES6 Variable Scoping: Can't access the value inside a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am trying to handle a timeout since last click.
**My main problem is that I can't seem to get the value of the var timeout inside the function**

```js
var timeouts = false;

const lastClickHide = () => {
  // always getting false
  console.log(timeouts);
  timeouts && clearTimeout(timeouts);
  // Reassign `timeouts`
  timeouts = setTimeout(() => console.log('4 seconds since last click'), 4000);
  return timeouts;
}
```

This is what am trying to execute:

- The first time the function is executed, `var timeouts` gets assigned the `timeout`, and
- The second time it's executed, `timeout` is saved in `timeouts` so that I can clear it if its already defined, but I can't recover that value.

Full code edit:

```
const Player = () => {

// Controls are hidden after 4secs since last click
  var timeouts = false
  const lastClickHide = () => {
    console.log(timeouts)
    timeouts && clearTimeout(timeouts)

    timeouts = setTimeout(() => console.log('4 seconds since last click'), 4000)

    return timeouts
  }

return (<TouchableOpacity
                style={{
                  width: 40,
                  height: 40,
                }}
                onPress={() => {
                  lastClickHide()
                }
              >
                <Icon name={'backward'} color="white" size={40} />
              </TouchableOpacity>)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a `React` component you have there, and on every render the `timeouts` variable will be re-declared, that's why you're losing its value.

The most simple solution is to move the declaration outside the component:

```
var timeouts = false; // <-- moved this outside the component

const Player = () => {

// Controls are hidden after 4secs since last click
  const lastClickHide = () => {
    console.log(timeouts)
    timeouts && clearTimeout(timeouts)

    timeouts = setTimeout(() => console.log('4 seconds since last click'), 4000)

    return timeouts
  }
[...]
```

If this is not acceptable, we could look into using `useMemo` to store the value of the `timeouts` variable between renders, just let me know and i'll write an example.